# Simple questions about local parameters for a relative smooth curve endowed with a section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\longrightarrow S$ be a morphism of preschemes which is smooth of pure relative dimension 1. Let $\sigma:S\longrightarrow X$ be a section of $X$. Let $D$ be the (positive) divisor associated to $\sigma$.

(1) Is this divisor automatically a relative(to $f$) one?
(2) If $x$ is a point of $D$, and $t$ a regular which generates $I(D)_x$. Does $t$ automatically has the property that $\mathcal O_x dt=(\Omega^1_{X/S})_x$?
(3) Does $t$ has automatically the property that $\mathcal{O}_s\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_x/t\mathcal{O}_x$ is an isomorphism?
(4) Questions (2) and (3) with $t$ a regular section of $\mathcal O_X$ over an open $U$ containing $x$ which generates $I(D)|_U$?

Comment: Yes. By $S$-flatness and Nakayama can reduce (2)--(4) to case $S$ is spec of field (even alg. closed). For (1), can assume $S$ noetherian, then local, then complete (by f. flatness reasons), say spec of $A$. The completed local ring on $X$ at special pt of section is abstractly $A[[t]]$ because local structure thm. for smooth maps gives etale map from $(X,x)$ to affine line (and etale maps induce formal isoms at residually trivial fibers). So enough that any $A$-alg. map $A[[t]] \rightarrow A$ has principal kernel. If $t \mapsto a$ then by *completeness* of $A$ can replace $t$ with $t-a$. QED

Comment: Dear workitout: It looks like you're still reading the early parts of Katz-Mazur.  I hope you have someone local with whom to discuss things in person.  Why did you give yourself the pseudonym "workitout"?

Comment: Dear Bcnrd, I'm not reading Katz-Mazur and I was not asking for any kind of reduction.

Comment: Dear workitout: I was giving you the key points of the arguments to *prove* the affirmative answers.  (That is, for (2) through (4), if you use flatness and Nakayama Lemma arguments you can get the result from the field case, a case which you presumably know how to do. For (1) one can't easily reduce to that case, which is why I gave you a more detailed explanation as to how to exploit the smoothness over the base ring.) Chapter 1 of Katz-Mazur covers many many things along the lines of your (1)--(4) (they even prove (1) in there somewhere), so I highly recommend that you read it. Enjoy!

Comment: Dear workitout: OK, now that I have K-M nearby I can tell you more: look at their Corollary 1.1.5.2.  They do give a nice overview about divisors, sometimes using external references, which may or may not make it useful, depending on your background.  For example, their Lemma 1.2.2 is exactly your (1). 

Comment: I'm quite sure that a section of a smooth morphism is very nice like it is a closed immersion which is also smooth, even regularly transversally immerged and here of codimension 1 so it is associated to a positive relative divisor(def. of EGA). So at a point of it there exists over an open $U$ of $X$ a section t which is non-zero-divisor, generates the kernel of $sigma$ and transversality should imply that its differential generates the whole $Omega^1_{U/S}$ (maybe after shrinking?) and by construction(as it comes from a section) $O_x/t_x O_x$ is isomorphic to $O_{S,f(x)}$. Where Am I wrong?

Comment: Dear Workitout: I think the proof of what you cite from EGA also uses the method of passing to fibers in order to access the commutative algebra of regular local rings, so it isn't essentially different from the Katz-Mazur argument to handle (1). Your idea for (2) is going to rest on Nakayama (I suppose), so again the same argument as what I suggested (which handles that part of (4) too).  And yes, (3) amounts to definitions.  So you're not wrong anywhere.  But when digging out the justifications for your strategy, it is not all that different (except for my initial suggestion on (1)).

Comment: Dear BCnrd: May I know which lines of EGA i'm citing? :) because I can't find anywhere something that asserts that if $\sigma$ is a section of a smooth morphism then $\sigma$ is at least smooth.


Comment: I'm quite sure that for K-M the morphism $f$ is not only smooth but also of finite presentation, what I do not assume here!

Comment: Dear workitout: smooth maps are loc. of finite pres. (that is part of the definition of smoothness, as in EGA), and your question is of local nature, so for your purposes finite pres. is automatic once you pass to affine setting. As for smooth subschemes of smooth schemes and properties thereof, section to separated map is closed immersion and so virtually never smooth. I thought you were referring to discussion in EGA about smooth subschemes of smooth schemes (regularly transversally embedded...). I think it's around section IV$_4$, 17.6. (Can't check easily right now.) 